repair fat usb storage
i tried mount:
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

tried gparted but i got no partition found error
i did device > partition table but take long time (more than 1 hour) with mkfs.fat & fsck
tried testdisk but i dont have partition table when i try unallocated to partition table waiting long time & freezing
tried fsck.fat /dev/sdb:
Logical sector size is zero.

if i trying fsck /dev/sdb:
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>


but if i trying e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sdb or e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb or any backup superblock getting same result above
mke2fs /dev/sdb waiting:
Creating filesystem with 7568640 4k blocks and 1892352 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 629eb0bf-2940-4eeb-a175-8c662e1f7a9a
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000

Allocating group tables: done

that too taking long time
tried so much thing in forums but still same problem like
How to restore my superblocks?

Sorry this is acting like a dead or dying drive.

You can analyze the problem according to this link and if you are lucky, find a solution.

@sudodus cannot working

@Bilinmiyor, If the drive does not work when you try according to that link, I am sorry, but I must agree with David, the drive is damaged beyond repair.

how can i fix it? any idea?

Pour some holy water over it. Say a prayer. Then bury it in your back yard. RIP :D

i agree u thx :D

This one is gone - for future reference, always have more than one copy of anything important ie.  backup.
